# Modifying the X-Axis Labels of a Scatterplot in Chart.js 2

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

In Chart.js 2 I am generating a scatter-plot where there x coordinates are Epoch timestamps and the y coordinates are integers. I was wondering if there was a way to format the x-axis labels of the graph, so that the dates are displayed in a human-readable format.

Update: Currently I am building my graph from Unix timestamps in milliseconds. The other parts of this prototype format those dates with the toDateString method of the Date class (eg. Fri Aug 5 2016).

Comment: Can you provide an example of desired format?
Also, provide an example of your current format.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For this you can make use of the `ticks.userCallback` in the `scales.xAxes` option so that you return a formatted date for each xaxis tick. If you are using the bundle version chartjs comes with momentjs which makes it really easy but if you are just passing timestamps in milliseconds you can do whatever you want to the label.

```
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                userCallback: function(label, index, labels) {
                    return moment(label).format("DD/MM/YY");
                }
             }
        ]}
     }
 }
```

fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/q5ak7p3h/

Comment: Is it any parameter for fixed x-axes and Y-axes, As I have used it dynamically and when our dataset is changed Axes for the graph also reflected.

Answer (score 3):

version 3.4 you can do it something like this:

```
 options: {
        scales: {
            x: {
                ticks: {
                    // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return '$' + value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```